# Defining log prestacks (and their structures)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

It's possible to define [log schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_structure), and Olsson's thesis defines [log stacks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2302/what-are-log-stacks).

Is there a definition of **log prestack** in the literature? Is it easy to extend Gaitsgory-Rozenblyum type results (construction and properties of [QCoh and IndCoh](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Egaitsgde/GL/IndCohtext.pdf), [crystals](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2087), etc.) to the log prestack situation, and has it been written down? If it is not easy, what are the main obstacles?